# HTML5 Drag and Drop for Quiz

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I'm making web-based quiz to help some people get some qualifications. After recently discovering the wonderful world of HTML5 (I've been previously programming in XHTML), I thought the ability to drag and drop a picture from a start box to an answer box would be a great addition to break up the monotony of lists, radio buttons, and textboxes.

I do not have access to PHP or JQUERY. (The site is meant to run on a box with no internet, nor do I have access to setup a web server to support PHP).

Is it possible, using JavaScript and four boxes/divs (one for the start position and three possible answer boxes), to determine which box/div the image is in?

Thank you very much!

Comment: jQuery _is_ JavaScript. You can use jQuery as a local resource with no dependency on an internet connection. Alternatively, you could implement the drag/drop functionality in (plain) vanilla JavaScript. Also, all of this was possible before HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

You can download jQuery (http://jquery.com/download/) and jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/download/) and add them to your page as a script

then take a look at draggable and droppable on the jQuery UI docs : http://jqueryui.com/droppable/